# Find items that don't have any entries in the link table with MySQL

Tags: mysql, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I have an `items` table and a `tags` table that are linked through a `user_tags` table. I have a query that finds all items with specific tags:

```
self::factory('item')
    ->join('user_tags', 'INNER')->on('items.id', '=', 'user_tags.item_id')
    ->join('tags', 'INNER')->on('user_tags.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')
    ->where('tags.title', 'IN', $array_of_tags);
```

or without kohana orm:

```
SELECT items.*
FROM items
INNER JOIN user_tags ON items.id = user_tags.item_id
INNER JOIN tags ON user_tags.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE tags.title IN ($array_of_tags);
```

I would like to find all items that have no tags associated to them. How would I do this?

Comment: You have 2 tags table: tags ans user tags? Which tags are the ones you do not want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add another where condition

```
SELECT 
    items.*
FROM items
LEFT JOIN user_tags ON items.id = user_tags.item_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON user_tags.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE tags.title IN ($array_of_tags)
AND user_tags.tag_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch your inner join to left join

```
SELECT items.*
FROM items
LEFT JOIN user_tags ON items.id = user_tags.item_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON user_tags.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE (tags.title IN ($array_of_tags) or tags.title is null)
and user_tags.item_Id is null.
```

Keep in mind SQL is not much more than set logic.

Here's a link to help explain the different type of joins.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
SELECT items.*
FROM items
LEFT JOIN user_tags ON items.id = user_tags.item_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON user_tags.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE 
user_tags.tag_id is null 
AND tags.title IN ($array_of_tags)
```